# Swift MetalKit buffer completion handler vs waitForCompletion?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, metal

When creating a render pass in MetalKit is it better in terms of performance to wait for completion or to add a completion handler? If I use the completion handler then I'll end up with a lot of nested closures, but I think waitForCompletion might block a thread. If the completion handler is preferred, is there a better way in Swift to do this without having to use so many nested closures?

For example,

```swift
buffer.addCompletionHandler { _ in
    ... next task
    buffer2.addCompletionHandler { _ in
        ... etc etc
    }
}
```

Comment: They both won't execute until the command queue is completed before running code either following the wait signal or  in the completion handler.

Comment: And of course waitForCompletion will block whatever thread it is called on until completed - that is kind of the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

The other people are right in telling you that this is probably not what you want to do, and you should go educate yourself on how others have created render loops in Metal.

That said, if you actually have use cases for non-blocking versions of  [`waitUntilCompleted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1443039-waituntilcompleted) or [`waitUntilScheduled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1443036-waituntilscheduled), you can create and use your own until Apple gets around to providing the same.

```swift
public extension MTLCommandBuffer {
  /// Wait until this command buffer is scheduled for execution on the GPU.
  var schedulingCompletion: Void {
    get async {
      await withUnsafeContinuation { continuation in
        addScheduledHandler { _ in
          continuation.resume()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /// Wait until the GPU has finished executing the commands in this buffer.
  var completion: Void {
    get async {
      await withUnsafeContinuation { continuation in
        addCompletedHandler { _ in
          continuation.resume()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I doubt those properties will improve any code, as all of the task ordering code, necessary to ensure that the "handlers" are added before `commit` is called, is worse than the callbacks.

```swift
let string: String = await withTaskGroup(of: String.self) { group in
  let buffer = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!.makeCommandQueue()!.makeCommandBuffer()!

  group.addTask {
    await buffer.schedulingCompletion
    return "2"
  }

  group.addTask {
    await buffer.completion
    return "3"
  }

  group.addTask {
    buffer.commit()
    return "1"
  }

  return await .init(group)
}

XCTAssertEqual(string, "123")
```

```swift
public extension String {
  init<Strings: AsyncSequence>(_ strings: Strings) async rethrows
  where Strings.Element == String {
    self = try await strings.reduce(into: .init()) { $0.append($1) }
  }
}
```

However, while I'm unconvinced on `addScheduledHandler` being improvable, I think pairing `addCompletedHandler` and `commit` has more potential.

```swift
public extension MTLCommandBuffer {
  /// Commit this buffer and wait for the GPU to finish executing its commands.
  func complete() async {
    await withUnsafeContinuation { continuation in
      self.addCompletedHandler { _ in
        continuation.resume()
      }

      commit()
    } as Void
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are supposed to use `MTLCommandQueue`s and `MTLEvent`s for serializing your GPU work, not completion handlers. Completion handlers are meant to be used only in cases where you need CPU-GPU synchronization. e.g. when you need to read back a result of GPU calculation on a CPU, or you need to add a back pressure, like for example when you only want to draw a certain amount of frame concurrently.

Comment: I wouldn't say "only" - perhaps it is used to remove a progress view or something.